# how to convert an associative array to cursor(SYS_REFCURSOR)

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors

I'm new at oracle collections. So please direct me in converting an associative array to cursor(SYS_REFCURSOR).

```
/*-----------my snippnet like this---*/
/*--declared in package*/
TYPE GENARRAY IS TABLE of NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
/*--defined in package body*/
1.FUNCTION GETXXX_GETFOLDERS1 (IN_ARRAY GENARRAY) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
OUTTABLE GENARRAY; 
GRPID NUMBER;
VCOUNT NUMBER:=0;
return_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
2. BEGIN 
FOR I IN 1..IN_ARRAY.COUNT LOOP

3. VCOUNT:=VCOUNT+1;
4.  SELECT GROUPID INTO GRPID FROM DMBI_GROUPDETAIL WHERE GROUPNAME IN (IN_ARRAY(I));
OUTTABLE(VCOUNT):=GRPID;
END LOOP;

5. Open return_cursor FOR
SELECT * FROM TABLE (CAST(OUTTABLE AS GENARRAY));

6. RETURN return_cursor;
END GETXXX_GETFOLDERS1; 

----ERROR on line which is in bold-----
Error(5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(5): PL/SQL: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*--declared in package*/
```

TYPE GENARRAY IS TABLE of NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

- is not the correct data structure that you need. Based on your comments i am assuming that the type is declared in package; but then you use variable of that type in cast :

  SELECT * FROM TABLE (CAST(OUTTABLE AS GENARRAY));

you can that only with custom SQL type (not pl/sql type).
you need:

```
create type  GENARRAY IS TABLE of NUMBER ;
```

you also will need a bit different usage of variable. [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58227/ch_objs.htm)